# Flask Request to get HTML data from a template?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Is it possible to get the html data from a template using flask requests?

For example, this is what I'm trying.

```
html = request.get_data(render_template('custom_templates/basic.html'))
```

Then pass that html info into the template:

```
 return render_template('index.html', html=html)
```

I can't view the basic.html file using the below URL (404 not found) which is why I'm trying to "render_template".
http://127.0.0.1:5000/templates/custom_templates/basic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this using make_response.

```
from flask import make_response

resp = make_response(render_template('custom_templates/basic.html'))
html = resp.get_data(as_text=True)
```

If you don't add `as_text=True` then it returns it in Bytes.